# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module - when running packaged Electron app

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules, package.json

When my node_modules folder is located in a root folder (not the same folder as where I ran the electron-packager command), I get `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'`.

I call require this way:
`window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');`

And my node_modules is located in: `C:\node_modules` to make sure all my apps will be able to use it.

What's weird is when I just do an `npm start`, it works fine.
Also, when the node_modules folder is located inside the same folder as my app and I call electron-packager, the packaged app works fine.

Can't electron-packager find the node_modules from a root folder??

Help!

Comment: All packaging tools I know expect that the necessary dependencies are locally installed in your project root folder - not some folder somewhere on your machine. I am actually surprised that `npm start` works as expected, as npm scripts prefer the locally installed dependencies. Is there a reason you don't want to install this module locally in your project folder?

Comment: Simply because we are working on multiple node projects and did not want to have a set of node_modules per project. 

From NodeJS documentation:
"If it (node_modules) is not found there, then it moves to the parent directory, and so on, until the root of the file system is reached." So putting it in C:/ allows all projects in C:/ to be able to use it.  I find it peculiar that node_modules is designed this way but such structure doesn't work with packagers.